# Can a TEMPORARY TABLE exist in more than one tab of pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

When I create a temporary table in one tab of pgAdmin 4, I can't use it in another. Can I somehow change that?

[image]

This is now in **another** query tab:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot help that, because these are two different database sessions, and a temporary table exists only in the session that created it.

Maybe you can use a normal table.

Comment: I just thought it's perhaps possible to make the second tab use the first session, too. Thank you.